# I seem to have an infinite while loop in my Swift code and I can't figure out why

Tags: swift, loops, while-loop, repeat, infinite

```
var array: [Int] = []
//Here I make an array to try to dictate when to perform an IBaction.

func random() -> Int {
   let rand = arc4random_uniform(52)*10+10
    return Int(rand)
} 
//this function makes a random integer for me


func finalRand() -> Int {
    var num = random()

    while (array.contains(num) == true){
        if (num == 520){
            num = 10
        }else {
            num += 10
        }

    }
    array.append(num)
    return num
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the array? To make sure you don't repeat a random number? In that case a `Set` is probably more appropriate.

Comment: Once you add all 52 possible random numbers, your code will go into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

The logic in the while statement is somewhat confusing, but you could try this:

```
var array:Array<Int> = []
func finalRand() -> Int {
    var num = Int(arc4random_uniform(52)*10+10)
    while array.contains(num) {
        num = Int(arc4random_uniform(52)*10+10)
    }
    array.append(num)
    return num
}
```

This way there will never be a repeat, and you have less boiler code.

There is probably a better method involving Sets, but I'm sorry I do not know much about that.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. Once your array has all 52 values, an attempt to add the 53rd number will end up in an infinite loop because all 52 values are already in your array.
2. In contemporary Swift versions, you can simplify your `random` routine to

   ```
   func random() -> Int {
       return Int.random(in: 1...52) * 10
   }
   ```
3. It seems like you might want a shuffled array of your 52 different values, which you can reduce to:

   ```
   let array = Array(1...52).map { $0 * 10 }
       .shuffled()
   ```

   Just iterate through that shuffled array of values.

   If you really need to continue generating numbers when you’re done going through all of the values, you could, for example, reshuffle the array and start from the beginning of the newly shuffled array.
4. As an aside, your routine will not generate truly random sequence. For example, let’s imagine that your code just happened to populate the values 10 through 500, with only 510 and 520 being the final possible remaining values: Your routine is 51 times as likely to generate 510 over 520 for the next value. You want to do a Fisher-Yates shuffle, like the built-in `shuffled` routine does, to generate a truly evenly distributed series of values. Just generate array of possible values and shuffle it.